# remove 1 from varible every spesific second

Tags: javascript, setinterval

so I've made a code like this
the goal is to make the console to say 10 to 0 then the console say done then exit the process

but I don't know why there is an error that says "Assignment to constant variable."

my code is down below here

```
const a = "10"

setInterval(() =>{
    a -= 1
         console.log(a)
    if(!a){
        console.log("done")
        process.exit()
    }
},1000)
```

Comment: use `let` instead of `const` as you want to reassign the value

Comment: BRUH OKAYY 
I DONT KNOW THAT
I hate my self

Comment: Check these links https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have declared `a` as constant in the first line. Change that declaration to let like this,

```
let a = "10"

setInterval(() =>{
    a -= 1
         console.log(a)
    if(!a){
        console.log("done")
        process.exit()
    }
},1000)
```